# Find/Replace in Xcode using Regular Expression

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following function calls at several places in my class.

```
[myClass doOperationOne];
[myClass doOperationTwo];
[myClass doOperationThree];
```

In those lines, I want to search for the following,

```
[myClass doOperationOne
[myClass doOperationTwo
[myClass doOperationThree
```

And replace them with the following, (by appending `WithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]`)

```
[myClass doOperationOneWithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]];
[myClass doOperationTwoWithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]];
[myClass doOperationThreeWithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]];
```

How can I do this using single Regular Expression Find/Replace?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Somehow I've managed to find the answer (which is enough for my need here) by referring the post: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/273123-how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-xcode-find-replace.html, and trial and error method.

My **Find** string is:

```
(\[myClass.myMethod )(.*)(\];)
```

And, my **Replace** string is:

```
\1\2WithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]\3
```

Please post if there is any better way than this..

Comment: that's my only qualm with regular expressions. replace behavior is not so standard. great that you found this.

Comment: Note that (see @Kalle's answer) this behavior changed in Xcode 6 to use $1, $2 instead of \1, \2

Answer (score 65):

**NOTE: The behavior changed in Xcode 6. The \123 syntax was replaced with $123. Also be warned that newlines can now be matched in reg exps so be sure to skim before Replace-Alling**

Adding an additional argument to a method:

To replace

```
[* setFoo:*]
```

with

```
[* setFoo:* bar:value]
```

you do

```
(setFoo:)(.*)(\])
$1$2 bar:value]
```

(search string and replacement string respectively).

or, if on Xcode 5 or older

```
(setFoo:)(.*)(\])
\1\2 bar:value]
```

(below uses new syntax; swap if on Xcode 5 or older)

**NOTE: Everything written here applies to the string-replacement methods in `NSString`/`NSMutableString` when using `NSRegularExpressionSearch`!**

In other words, this line:

```
[input replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\\[([^\\]^\n]*)\\]\n" 
                       withString:@"\n///\n\n[$1]\n" 
                          options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                            range:(NSRange){0,input.length}];
```

will convert all `"[...]\n"` sequences (leaving e.g. `"[...\n..."` alone!) into `"\n///\n\n[...]\n"`, preserving `...` using $1.

Always did this by hand but in this case, I was adding an OPTIONAL 'animate:' flag, and the default up to this point had been YES, but I wanted NO, so every call had to be updated.

More examples:

### Deprecated methods (iOS)

**`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:...` deprecation**

To fix the deprecated `dismissModalViewController` replacing it with an empty completion block and retaining animated value:

```
(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)(.*)(\])
dismissViewControllerAnimated:$2 completion:nil]
```

---

**`presentModalViewController:animated:` deprecation**

```
(presentModalViewController:)(.*)( animated:)(.*)(\])
presentViewController:$2$3$4 completion:nil]
```

### Miscellaneous

**PD...Release → PD...Destroy**

I recently wrote a c library with a bunch of files with the prefix `PD` and I used Create/Release as malloc/free keywords, which I regretted as it may make people think retain counting is kept, so I wanted to rename`PD<anything>Release(` with `PD<anything>Destroy(`.

```
([\n\r ])(PD)(.*)Release\(
$1$2$3Destroy(
```

Since Core Graphics has `CGPDFDocumentRelease` and similar, I had to ensure the word *started* with PD as well.

---

**<strike>`PDAssert(`</strike>`PDScannerPop...(...)`<strike>`)`</strike>`;`**

I had stupidly put assertions around functional code that would become empty when !#ifdef DEBUG. Luckily I knew that all of these started with PDAssert(PDScannerPop.... and ended with );.

```
(PDAssert\()(PDScannerPop)(.*)(\);)
$2$3;
```

No $1 here because that would include the `PDAssert(` again. Note that I've split right after the PDAssert( and am leaving out the ) in ); in the 3rd chunk which removes the surplus parens from removing PDAssert(.

***Dealing with end parentheses***

You can match everything except ")" to deal with over-greedy regexp replaces. Example:

```
foo(replace(arg), bar)
foo(newvalue(newarg), bar)
```

Using `replace\((.*)\)` will grab `replace(arg), bar)` and result will be `foo(newvalue(newarg)`! Instead use `replace\(([^\)]*)\)` which will grab `replace(arg)` and leave `, bar)` alone.

***Converting a bunch of NSString properties from using retain and/or strong (and whatever else) to using copy***

```
@property \(([^\)]*)[sr][te][rt][oa][ni][gn]([^\)]*)\)(.*)NSString(.*)
@property ($1copy$2)$3NSString$4
```

The weird sr te rt thing in the center matches both "strong" and "retain".

Comment: String replacement does not appear to work for find/replace in a single file.

Comment: I use it all the time. What are your search and replace strings?

Answer (score 24):

## Note for Xcode 8

I was trying to update my answer below for Xcode 8, but I couldn't do it. [If you have the answer, please let me know.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605853/find-and-replace-using-patterns-in-xcode-8)

## Xcode 7

Unless you were already a regular expression genius, this much easier to do in Xcode now. You don't need to use regular expressions at all (but you can if you still want to).

## Example

Replace these strings:

> [myClass doOperation**One**];
> [myClass doOperation**Two**];
> [myClass doOperation**Three**];

with these strings

> [myClass doOperation**One**WithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]];
> [myClass doOperation**Two**WithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]];
> [myClass doOperation**Three**WithOptions:[Permissions
> isOptionsAvailable]];

The bolded numbers show why a plain Find and Replace won't work.

## Setup

There are two ways you can do Find and Replace: **Textual** and **Regular Expression**

Click the magnifying glass

[image]

and "Edit Find Options..."

[image]

and choose one of them.

[image]

## Method 1 - Textual

- Enter `[myClass doOperation` in Find
- Click the magnifying class and choose "Insert Pattern"

[image]

- Choose "Any Word Characters"

[image]

- Add `];` to Find

[image]

- Repeat for the Replacement String but use `WithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]];` for the last part.

[image]

- A single Replace All will work now.

## Method 2 - Regular Expression

- Make sure that Regular Expressions are selected as described in Setup above.
- Use `(\[myClass doOperation)(.*)(\];)` for the Regular Expression
- Use `$1$2WithOptions:[Permissions isOptionsAvailable]$3` for the Replacement String. The `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` replace the parentheses in the regular expression.

[image]

- A single Replace All will work now.
- See [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial) for more help with regular expressions.

## See also

- [How can I find and replace inside a selection in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630754/3681880)

Answer (score 7):

on **Xcode 11+**

for example:

when you use `view(.*)Appear` to find all viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

and replaced by `args: $1`

You will get the result as follow

[image]

**Don't forget** to use `()` to wrap the `.*`, or you will get an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything saying that regular expression capture and replace is supported WITHIN Xcode.

you would want

```
\[myClass\.myMethod\sdoOperation([A-Z][a-z]+)\]
```

to capture the number. though. that is what the parenthesis are for.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Xcode, I believe you can only search using regular expressions. Replace doesn't give you that flexibility. If you only have three methods you want to replace in this manner, I would run search and replace three times. Otherwise, I would modify my source code in BASH using awk or sed.

Comment: Both Find and Replace in Workspace and Find and Replace in a single file support regular expressions. Put your cursor on the magnifying glass in the search filed, clock the pull down arrow and select "Show Find Options". Not sure which engine they use, you'd think something ICU based like NSPredicate, but it had no problem recognizing \n replacement patterns which are PCRE (which is what BBEdit uses). Only problem is that it refuses to capture or replace carriage returns or line breaks (\r \n). No documentation that I could find.