# (REGEX) Regular Expression to replace all in Xcode 5

Tags: regex, xcode5

I have about 1,300 instances of

```
#import <xxxxx/ClassName.h>
```

that I'd like to replace with

```
#import "ClassName.h"
```

I noticed if I use the cmd-shift-f menu I can go to Replace > Regular Expression.  The ClassName is not unique, xxxxx is always the same.

What is the regular expression that will replace all of those?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### In Xcode 5:

As **Find** string:

```
#import <xxxxx/(\w+\.h)>
```

As **Replace** string:

```
#import "\1"
```

---

### In Xcode 6:

**Note:** The behavior **changed** in **Xcode 6**. The `\1` syntax was replaced with `$1`. Also keep in mind that newlines can now be matched in regular expressions, so make sure to skim before doing a  Replace All.

Comment: if you are looking for an answer that works in xcode6 you'll find it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208449/416184 basically you have to write $1 instead of \1

Comment: Damn Xcode 6 changing the syntax, took me a while to find the solution, thank you sir.