# Find and Replace using patterns in Xcode 8

Tags: regex, xcode, xcode8

I was trying to update [one of my old Xcode 7 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631589/3681880) that described how to do regular expression matching. However, I can't get the Textual Matching Style to work now. In Xcode 7, I could do something like this:

[image]

which gave me pattern matching like this:

[image]

But in Xcode 8 the green bubbles don't show up. I get a `(\w+)` but that doesn't match anything in the Textual style anymore. And when I am in The Regular Expression Matching Style, I don't have all the nice Insert Pattern hints anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm not asking for the regex answer. I'm asking how to get the Insert Pattern hints to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched your find options *Matching Style* from *Text* to *Regular Expression*. To revert this, simply click on the magnifying glass next to the search field, select `Edit find options...` and set the *Matching Style* back to text.

[image: Edit Find Options...]
[image: Select matching style]